# For ESB4, how to access the in sequence message at out seqence

Tags: jms, wso2, wso2-esb

We are using ESB4 proxy service with in sequence and out sequence. the message being mediated during in sequence and send to endpoint. the response goes to out sequence. we like to filter the response such as auth failure and to put the inbound message back to JMS store for retry. But I don't know how to get hold of the message at out sequence. Would appreciate the help.

Comment: For reference, you may have to include the code you're using. This question is a little vague (at least to me) otherwise.

Comment: Maybe I will ask differently. how do you access the REQUEST message  at the outsequence when you process the response message? The use case is that I want to send the request message to store for retry if the response is not what I expected.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a message store in your outsequence to hold the message...Define a message store and use that in store meditaor. Find samples here

http://wso2.org/project/esb/java/4.0.0/docs/samples/store_n_forward_samples.html

Comment: Sorry that I didn't explain the issue clearly. if we put a store in outsequence like this: <syn:store messageStore="MyStore"/> the response message will be sent to the store. but we what want is the request message rather than response message. the use case is like this: a request message was sent to endpoint, if the response code is not 0, then we need to retry that REQUEST message by put it into the message store. but I don't know how to get hold of the REQUEST message at outsequence.

Comment: Not sure this can be achieved with the message processor, since after the successful delivery of the message, message will be removed from the store..But you can define a property mediator @ your inSequence to hold the incoming request and use that in your outsequence to resend the message again to same endpoint.